# In python pandas, how to fill NaN value to nearest past Value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Filling NaN value in Pandas Dataframe is easy when the replacing value is static.

But what I need to do is iterating through column from index 0 and remember the last observed non-NaN value and replace NaN value with it.

```
index       cur_price 
2017-07-01  1000
2017-07-02  NaN
2017-07-03  12000
2017-07-04  13000
2017-07-05  NaN
2017-07-06  9000
2017-07-07  9500
2017-07-08  NaN
2017-07-09  NaN
```

it should be become

```
index       cur_price
2017-07-01  1000
2017-07-02  1000
2017-07-03  12000
2017-07-04  13000
2017-07-05  13000
2017-07-06  9000
2017-07-07  9500
2017-07-08  9500
2017-07-09  9500
```

Is there good functionality in pandas for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
df.ffill()


Out[17]: 
        index  cur_price
0  2017-07-01     1000.0
1  2017-07-02     1000.0
2  2017-07-03    12000.0
3  2017-07-04    13000.0
4  2017-07-05    13000.0
5  2017-07-06     9000.0
6  2017-07-07     9500.0
7  2017-07-08     9500.0
8  2017-07-09     9500.0
```